# Iterate through nested properties when some may be generic

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("VidallyEF") {}

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contest> Contests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to iterate through the properties of MyContext, and then through the properties of each of those properties. I have this:

```
foreach (var table in typeof(MyContext).GetProperties())
            {
                // TODO add check that table is DbSet<TEntity>..not sure..

                PropertyInfo[] info = table.GetType().GetProperties();

                foreach (var propertyInfo in info)
                {
                    //Loop 
                    foreach (var attribute in propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false))
                    {
                        if (attribute is MyAttribute)
                        {
                           //do stuff
                        }
                    }
                }        

            }
```

The problem is that because the Properties of MyContext are generics, the GetType().GetProperties() is not returning the properties of the underlying objects. Some how I need to get to User and Role object.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things available on PropertyInfo that will be helpful. `IsGenericType` will tell you whether the property type is generic and the `GetGenericArguments()` call will return a `Type` array containing the types of the generic type parameters.

```
foreach (var property in someInstance.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
    {
        var genericArguments = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
        //Do something with the generic parameter types                
    }
}
```

It's also important to note that `GetProperties()` only returns the properties available on the specified type. If you want types that may be *contained or used by* your specified type, you will have to do a little bit of digging to get them.

Comment: Thanks  - PropertyType was the missing link for me.